# Merge and restructure Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

My resulting object is like this :

```
[{
  "device": {
    "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1",
    "serialNumber": "100000100215",

    "patientRiskStatus": "high",
    "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z"
  },
  "firstName": "userName"
}]
```

I want to convert this object structure to this:

```
[{

  "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1",
  "serialNumber": "100000100215",
  "firstName": "userName",
  "patientRiskStatus": "high",
  "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z",
}]
```

This is my code -

```
var filteredDevices = []
var result = []

if (user.role === 'Nurse') {
  devices.forEach((device) => {
    filteredDevices.push({
      device: device,
      firstName: "userName"
    })
    result = filteredDevices.map(({ device, ...rest }) => ({
      ...rest,
      ...device
    }))
  })
}
```

I tried the solution suggested below it looks fine in snippet sample but my node.js just behaves differently I am not sure why.

Below result I get when trying the solutions. not sure why it gives me this long result.

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Rikin",
        "__parentArray": [
            {
                "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1",
                "serialNumber": "100000100215",
                "area": "Office 1",
                "connectionStatus": 0,
                "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a1",
                "applicationNumber": 40,
                "firmwareVersion": "v12.1.8",
                "needsAttention": true,
                "verificationCode": "4144",
                "patientRiskStatus": "high",
                "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa2",
                "serialNumber": "100000100216",
                "area": "Office 2",
                "connectionStatus": 0,
                "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a1",
                "applicationNumber": 41,
                "firmwareVersion": "v12.1.8",
                "needsAttention": true,
                "verificationCode": "4145",
                "patientRiskStatus": "low",
                "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa3",
                "serialNumber": "100000100217",
                "area": "Office 4",
                "connectionStatus": 0,
                "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a1",
                "applicationNumber": 60,
                "firmwareVersion": "v12.1.8",
                "needsAttention": true,
                "verificationCode": "4146",
                "patientRiskStatus": "low",
                "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z"
            }
        ],
        "__index": 0,
        "$isDocumentArrayElement": true,
        "$__": {
            "strictMode": true,
            "getters": {},
            "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1",
            "wasPopulated": false,
            "activePaths": {
                "paths": {
                    "_id": "init",
                    "serialNumber": "init",
                    "area": "init",
                    "connectionStatus": "init",
                    "gatewayKey": "init",
                    "applicationNumber": "init",
                    "firmwareVersion": "init",
                    "needsAttention": "init",
                    "verificationCode": "init",
                    "patientRiskStatus": "init",
                    "createdAt": "init",
                    "updatedAt": "init"
                },
                "states": {
                    "ignore": {},
                    "default": {},
                    "init": {
                        "_id": true,
                        "serialNumber": true,
                        "area": true,
                        "connectionStatus": true,
                        "gatewayKey": true,
                        "applicationNumber": true,
                        "firmwareVersion": true,
                        "needsAttention": true,
                        "verificationCode": true,
                        "patientRiskStatus": true,
                        "createdAt": true,
                        "updatedAt": true
                    },
                    "modify": {},
                    "require": {}
                },
                "stateNames": [
                    "require",
                    "modify",
                    "init",
                    "default",
                    "ignore"
                ]
            },
            "pathsToScopes": {},
            "cachedRequired": {},
            "$setCalled": {},
            "ownerDocument": {
                "apiCallCount": 0,
                "_id": "58dc5b9f3107602dbaba1281",
                "email": "rikyshah@gmail.com",
                "password": "password",
                "userName": "rikyshah",
                "companyName": "RS company",
                "apiKey": "Hhd87AD&jasd90dlK09aosdO",
                "buildings": [
                    {
                        "gateways": [
                            {
                                "devices": [
                                    {
                                        "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1",
                                        "serialNumber": "100000100215",
                                        "area": "Office 1",
                                        "connectionStatus": 0,
                                        "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a1",
                                        "applicationNumber": 40,
                                        "firmwareVersion": "v12.1.8",
                                        "needsAttention": true,
                                        "verificationCode": "4144",
                                        "patientRiskStatus": "high",
                                        "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa2",
                                        "serialNumber": "100000100216",
                                        "area": "Office 2",
                                        "connectionStatus": 0,
                                        "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a1",
                                        "applicationNumber": 41,
                                        "firmwareVersion": "v12.1.8",
                                        "needsAttention": true,
                                        "verificationCode": "4145",
                                        "patientRiskStatus": "low",
                                        "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa3",
                                        "serialNumber": "100000100217",
                                        "area": "Office 4",
                                        "connectionStatus": 0,
                                        "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a1",
                                        "applicationNumber": 60,
                                        "firmwareVersion": "v12.1.8",
                                        "needsAttention": true,
                                        "verificationCode": "4146",
                                        "patientRiskStatus": "low",
                                        "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "_id": "5d254b64ba574040d9632ada",
                                "gatewayName": "RBC-xaka-001",
                                "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a1",
                                "suite": "RBC1",
                                "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z"
                            },
                            {
                                "devices": [
                                    {
                                        "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa0",
                                        "serialNumber": "100000100214",
                                        "area": "Office 3",
                                        "connectionStatus": 0,
                                        "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a2",
                                        "applicationNumber": 60,
                                        "firmwareVersion": "v12.1.8",
                                        "needsAttention": true,
                                        "verificationCode": "4147",
                                        "patientRiskStatus": "low",
                                        "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "_id": "5d254b7174d7b3a73dff342f",
                                "gatewayName": "RBC-xaka-002",
                                "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a2",
                                "suite": "RBC2",
                                "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5d254bb179584ebcbb68b712",
                        "buildingName": "RBC Bank Tower",
                        "address": "1 Front Street East",
                        "suite": "110",
                        "floor": "2nd floor",
                        "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
                        "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z"
                    }
                ],
                "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z"
            },
            "fullPath": "buildings.gateways.devices",
            "emitter": {
                "_events": {},
                "_eventsCount": 2,
                "_maxListeners": 0
            },
            "$options": {}
        },
        "isNew": false,
        "_doc": {
            "_id": "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1",
            "serialNumber": "100000100215",
            "area": "Office 1",
            "connectionStatus": 0,
            "gatewayKey": "gk_d0202d93d0d29293a1",
            "applicationNumber": 40,
            "firmwareVersion": "v12.1.8",
            "needsAttention": true,
            "verificationCode": "4144",
            "patientRiskStatus": "high",
            "createdAt": "2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z"
        },
        "$locals": {},
        "$init": true
    },.....
```

Answer (score 5):

Iterate the array with `Array.map()`. In the callback, destructure the `device` property, and use rest syntax to get the rest of the object.

Reconstruct the object by spreading the `device` and the rest of the original object into a new object.

```js
const arr = [{"device":{"_id":"5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1","serialNumber":"100000100215","patientRiskStatus":"high","createdAt":"2017-04-16T01:22:00.000Z","updatedAt":"2020-01-01T05:29:19.632Z"},"firstName":"userName"}]
    
const result = arr.map(({ device, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  ...device
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: code snippet looks prefect but my node.js code just gives me long result as I pasted in my question.

Comment: Note that this creates a new array, and doesn't mutate the original array.

Comment: The original input structure and what you've shown in the question are not identical. In addition, you're filtering the data using a `user` object, which doesn't appear in the question. I suggest that you open a new question, and add the original input, your original code, and the desired output.